# How to select an active record based on date range using from and to dates

Tags: date-range

A person may be placed at multiple locations throughout their life.  The table used to store this information have from and to dates.  Their current location will have a start date but `NULL` as the end date.  All earlier placements will have a start and and end date.

The business then ask me to provide the name of the location they were at for a particular date, how would I write the sql to find the correct period and get the right location name?

I'm not sure how to proceed.

In this example, I am told the date to find the placement name for 13/03/2019.

The correct result would be: `Overseas`.

If I was given a date of `18/01/2011`, then it would be `city`

```
cg_placementstartdate        cg_placementenddate        Placement Name
2011-01-17 00:00:00.000      2011-09-19 00:00:00.000    City
2011-04-12 00:00:00.000      2011-04-20 00:00:00.000    State
2011-09-19 00:00:00.000      NULL                       Overseas
```

Comment: Which language are you using? What did you tried so far?

Comment: Which database are you using? What did you tried so far?

Comment: Fixed formatting